# How to extend built-in object "Set" to get the last stored value?

Tags: javascript, class, methods, set

I want to extend the build-in js object, **Set**, to give it more functionality. I would like to be able to get the value of the item that was stored last. My code snippet does that,

```js
class MySet extends Set {
  add(value) {
    super.add(value);
    this.last = value;
  }
}

let a = new MySet([1, 2, 3]);
a.add(1);
console.log(a.last); //1
```

but there is an issue if I try adding a duplicate value. In the following snippet, the last stored value is 3, and not 1, but with my method I get a 1.

So I have been wondering how could I extend it so that I would get the actual last stored value.

Comment: Are you sure `a.last` is not `undefined` (you say it's `1`...). Also, don't misuse `let`. Use `const`

Comment: You'd need to do `new MySet` instead of `new Set` for a start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple workaround

```js
class MySet extends Set {
  add(value) {
    if (!super.has(value)) {
      super.add(value);
      this.last = value;
    }
  }
}

let a = new MySet([1, 2, 3]);
a.add(1);
console.log(a.last); //3
```

Answer (score 1):

The code provided by the OP does exactly what it is supposed to do ... `a.add(1);` of the enhanced set object just delegates to the original prototypal `add`, and without counterchecking if the added value does not already exist, this value is assumed to be the (thus stored as) last one.

A safe approach might implement a prototypal `last` method that always takes the currently last value from the set ...

```js
class SetWithLastValueGetter extends Set {
  last() {

    const valueList = [...this.values()];
  //const valueList = [...this.keys()];
  //const valueList = [...this];

    return valueList[valueList.length - 1];
  }
}
const enhancedSet = new SetWithLastValueGetter([1, 2, 3]);

enhancedSet.add(1);

// expect 3 as return value.
console.log(
  'enhancedSet.last() : ',
  enhancedSet.last()
);

enhancedSet.add(2);

// expect 3 as return value.
console.log(
  'enhancedSet.last() : ',
  enhancedSet.last()
);

enhancedSet.add(4);

// expect 4 as return value.
console.log(
  'enhancedSet.last() : ',
  enhancedSet.last()
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```